# Is there a way to do some ng-model of a non-input form element?

Tags: angular

I have a form with 50 fields. I want to preview to the user what they typed in the form in my template like this:

```
<div> STRING RESULT {{textfield1}} - {{textfield2}} - 3 {{textfield3}}</div>
```

I wanted to store this into a variable

```
<div [(ngModel)]="myresultmodel"> STRING RESULT {{textfield1}} - {{textfield2}} - 3 {{textfield3}}</div>
```

The problem when I do that is I get:

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

Is this not possible/shunned upon? Or is there a good way to do this?

Note: The result I am looking for is a single variable that contains the entire string within the div: "STRING RESULT {{textfield1}} - {{textfield2}} - 3 {{textfield3}}"

Comment: How do text fields look like?

Comment: <input [(ngModel)="textfield1" name="textfield1">, ...

Comment: Why not just write in your component: `GetMyResultModel() { return "STRING RESULT " + textfield1 + " - " + textfield2 + " - 3 " + textfield3; }` and write `{{GetMyResultModel()}}` in your div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the inner HTML of the div with `ViewChild`.

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lvrzf5YtJ1i0wlVRsdYj?p=preview)

I use the `doCheck` lifecycle to automatically update the result. The doCheck occurs before actually rendering the HTML, so you have to wrap the refresh in an async closure. Just call `setTimeout` without any timer do the trick.

I'm not a big fan of using the `setTimeout` hack. I think you can inject the changeDetector and call the changeDetection manually. But calling the changeDetection inside the doCheck can have side effect.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want  a single variable in the component that contains the entire string "STRING RESULT {{myresultmodel.textfield1}} - {{myresultmodel.textfield2}} - 3 {{myresultmodel.textfield3}}" as is.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand the question